# I messed up my git tree. Can I rearrange it or should I start over?

Tags: javascript, git, express, github

I have been learning web development for several months and just finished my first project. However, before deploying I messed up my backend side git tree.

I tried to fix it as shown in other answers but couldn't solve. Tried to reset to previous state but it already got too complicated for me. Is there are any way i can rearrange it or should I give up and fix everything from start?

[image]

Comment: How exactly is it messed up?

Comment: What is the other answer btw

Comment: An obligatory xkcd: https://xkcd.com/1597/. Just do as it suggests.

Comment: Sorry (first time posting here), I meant other answers related to git tree questions.   I wanted to merge develop and master but instead lines got tangled‍♂️.

Comment: You can undo basically anything in Git by checking out branches and resetting them to known good commits. You haven't "messed anything up" - you just aren't familiar enough with Git to be able to describe your current situation. This question will require lots of comments to understand your issue so it's probably not appropriate for Stackoverflow.

Comment: From the graph, is it correct that you merge develop into master from other web git interface and your local master branch is not yet in sync with origin/master? if that's the case you can simply force push your local master to force rewind the origin/master back to before merging develop

Comment: Thank you everyone.  Problem fixed. As @AndyRay said I was too dump yet to understand git so I hired  someone to help me. We deleted unnecessary merges and sync all branches.

Answer (score 0):

Start an interactive rebase from the root (first) commit.

```
git rebase --interactive --root
```

If you don't wish to make any other adjustments, save and close the file that opens. This will remove the merge commits to clean up the history.